# Correct way to deliever images from RESTful api

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I work an API that should read all the images stored in the Amazon S3 bucket and deliver to the front-end to display (and further operations).
I can use the code to access all the images stored but what is the correct format to deliver them to the FE?

Mt code is provided here,

```
@GetMapping(value = "/findAllImages")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> findNamesOfAllImages() {

        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

        String password = ProcBuilder.run(
                "security",
                "-i", "find-generic-password",
                "-l", Parameters.getAppName(), "-w"
        );

        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
                Parameters.getAccessKey(),
                password
        );

        AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                .build();

        ObjectListing objectListing = s3client.listObjects(Parameters.getBucketName());

        for (S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
            names.add(s3ObjectSummary.getKey());
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(names);
    }
```

ATM I only read the names of the images and store them in a `ArrayList`

Comment: Could you please detail the exact problem you are facing; the statement 'read all the images stored in the Amazon S3 bucket and deliver to the front-end to display (and further operations)' in unclear.

Comment: Ok, as you can see, I can access and retrieve the objects from the AWS S3. What's the correct format to deliver to the frontend? May be to save all the images as java File and deliver the? In that case, how to make files from the  `S3ObjectSummary `?

Comment: Not clear what you intend to do here. Do you want to send the content of the S3Objects i.e. the image data, the keys, what exactly do you want to send to the front end? From your code, you are sending a list of keys.

Comment: I want to send the data to the FE so they can show the images in the HTML page and work with them. I provided the code below as an answer. Maybe you can have a look and tell me if this is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the `OutputStream` for the purpose to send the data to the FE. I am not completely sure this is the way to go, but, here is the code provided.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/findAllImages")
    public ResponseEntity<List<OutputStream>> findNamesOfAllImages() {

        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

        String password = ProcBuilder.run(
                "security",
                "-i", "find-generic-password",
                "-l", Parameters.getAppName(), "-w"
        );

        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
                Parameters.getAccessKey(),
                password
        );

        AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                .build();

        ObjectListing objectListing = s3client.listObjects(Parameters.getBucketName());

        for (S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
            names.add(s3ObjectSummary.getKey());
        }

        List<OutputStream> outputStreams = new ArrayList<>();
        S3Object object = null;

        File file;
        int count = 0;

        for (String name : names) {

            object = s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(Parameters.getBucketName(), name));;

            InputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(object.getObjectContent());
            file = new File(name + (++count));

            OutputStream writer;

            try {

                writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                int read = -1;

                while (true) {

                    if (!((read = reader.read()) != -1))
                        break;

                    writer.write(read);
                    outputStreams.add(writer);
                }

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                reader.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(outputStreams);
    }
```